# In CouchDB shows, what does 'this' refer to?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I'm trying to understand CouchDB and couchapp, and as I'm going through I'm seeing a dearth of the use of 'this' in any given context.  I understand that `show` objects get the document and the request, and are allowed to operate on them with lists and views.   These operations are all Javascript objects.  But CouchApp also seems to store, as strings, all sorts of things: README files, Mustache templates, and so on.  It must have access to them somehow.  Does the `this` operator in the context of a `show` provide access to the design document root in some way, giving one access to objects by some means other than the `require` syntax?

In Javascript, `this` has to be defined *somehow* in every context, specifically "There is a **this** value associated with every active execution context. The **this** value depends on the caller and the type of code being executed and is determined when control enters the execution context. The **this** value associated with an execution context is immutable" (ECMA-262 Spec, 3rd edition, section 10.1.7).  What does it mean in the context of an executing CouchDB design doc `show` function?  A `view` or `list` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` variable, in all cases (_list, _show, _update) is the design document itself.

(Strictly speaking, it refers to a JavaScript object representation of the design document that contains the list/show/view function you are operating out of.)

Comment: +1. I hope you don't mind, but I edited your answer to be definitive and more confident (since it is in fact totally correct).

Comment: You will also see a lot of code where the first line of such functions is `var ddoc = this;`. Later, they will say `ddoc.views.foo` or `ddoc.templates.bar` because it feels natural.

Comment: Ah, okay.  It's still hard to find good examples of CouchDB design docs that aren't laden with a megaton of couchapp or kanso framework extras.  That's where ddoc comes from.  Thanks much!